# Web data scraping using Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I am using scrapy to scrape justdial.com but the code doesn't seem to work. Please help me fix this. I run it with the command being "scrapy crawl justdial -o items.csv -t csv" from the terminal.

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from justdial_sample.items import JustdialSampleItem

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "justdial"
    allowed_domains = ["www.justdial.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.justdial.com/"]

    rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("index\d00\.html",
    ),restrict_xpaths=('//p[@id="nextpage"]',))
    , callback="parse_items", follow=True),
    )  

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles = hxs.select("//p")
        items = []
        for titles in titles:
            item = JdItem()
            item ["title"] = titles.select("a/text()").extract()
            item ["link"] = titles.select("@/href").extract()
            item.append(item)
        return items
```

this is the code that I used.

Comment: AFAIK justdial blocks any other scrapers apart from Google. It's does not just restricted through the [`robots.txt`](https://us.justdial.com/robots.txt) file but they disallow IP addresses. You can try to play around with `USER_AGENT` string in scrapy or try using scrapy splash.

Answer (score 0):

If you can show output log it will be easier to help you.

Usually you should add correct headers as in browser, etc User-Agent. You can check all headers in firebug and you can check headers in your spider.

```
print response.request.headers
```

UPDATE:
You should add this row to settings.py

```
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0'
```

Comment: I need 10 reputation to post images. So I'm giving you a drive link instead.

Comment: You see 403 code (access denied) without user-agent.
I check you code on my site with UA and it's works.

Comment: This is the link to the image of the output I'm getting after applying the UA changes.

Comment: Change 
item = JdItem()
to
item = JustdialSampleItem()

Comment: Getting this after changing JdItem

Comment: Next problems - it's not by scrapy. It's problem of your code. Your code has much errors. I can not fix all your errors, i can help you if you have really problems.

Comment: so how do I fix this error? Atleast you can tell me how to and I'll do it.

Comment: check your xpaths, check you logic in script
Or hire someone for develop script for you.